# Disambiguate the [postfix] tag

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

The [postfix](/questions/tagged/postfix) tag is described as being for the mailer; however, a number of folks use it when describing issues with infix and postfix notation.

Can we make  [postfix-mailer](/questions/tagged/postfix-mailer) and [postfix-notation](/questions/tagged/postfix-notation) tags and blacklist [postfix](/questions/tagged/postfix)?

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe `postfix-mta` instead of `-mailer`?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, there are very few [postfix-notation](/questions/tagged/postfix-notation) questions as compared to [postfix-mailer](/questions/tagged/postfix-mailer). I suggest we first retag all [postfix-notation](/questions/tagged/postfix-notation) questions as such, and then rename/merge [postfix](/questions/tagged/postfix) to [postfix-mailer](/questions/tagged/postfix-mailer).

I've already started on some retagging. <s>[This search should help catch the bulk of mistagged posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix%5D%20infix%20is:question)</s>

Update: Finished retagging those posts. Now onwards with:

<s>https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix%5D+notation+is%3Aquestion</s>

The following searches cannot be blanket-retagged, look carefully:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix%5D+prefix+is%3Aquestion

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix%5D+-mail+-server+-smtp+-email+is%3Aquestion

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostfix%5D+operator+is%3Aquestion

That ought to cover all of the mistagged questions.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that we need more tags.  Ugh.  I've cleaned up a few questions that were talking about the post-increment operator `++`, but there are some C++ questions that are talking about postfix operators in general and I'm not really knowledgeable enough to attack those...